# How to create email addresses using SQL - duplicate names

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table with the first_name and last_name of the employees of a company.
So I tried to do a simple query by concatenating the names and adding "@mycompany.com".

```
SELECT first_name || last_name || '@mycompany.com' AS employee_email
FROM employee
```

My result was:

```
"JaredEly@mycompany.com"
"MarySmith@mycompany.com"
"PatriciaJohnson@mycompany.com"
"LindaWilliams@mycompany.com"
"BarbaraJones@mycompany.com"
```

However, I don't know how to handle cases where I will have duplicate names.

For instance, my base might have two people named John Smith, so I should have one with the email address "JohnSmith@mycompany.com" and the other one with the email address "JohnSmith2@mycompany.com", and so on.

Comment: Is this a for-real company thing? Or is a school thing? If it's real world, I'd say just generate them all according to your plan, then handle any duplicates on a case by case basis. And employees are going to be really annoyed if you name them "johnsmith2@mycompany.com". Better to use the middle initial or something when there's exceptions, like "johngsmith@mycompany.com"

Comment: It's for real, but I'm new on this. Please how should I handle the situation? Even with the middle initial or some number. Because some people don't have a middle name and then I guess I will have another problem. Thanks.

Comment: Like I said, handle it on a case by case basis. Generate the email according to your convention, then go find all duplicates and figure out how to handle them. How many duplicates do you have? A few? Dozens? Hundreds? Thousands? If this is a one time process, handling up to a few dozen duplicates by hand isn't too much manual work. And if some people don't have a middle initial, chances are the other person that shares their name does. Or they have a nickname you can use. Think about solutions, don't just give up at the first issue you hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a running number using the `row_number` window function:

```sql
SELECT first_name || 
       last_name || 
       CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name 
                               ORDER BY     1)
            WHEN 1 THEN ''
            ELSE ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name 
                                    ORDER BY     1)::varchar
       END ||
       '@mycompany.com' AS employee_email
FROM   employee
```

or, more elegantly, using a CTE so you don't have to repeat the `row_number` expression:

```sql
WITH e AS (
  SELECT first_name, 
         last_name, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY first_name, last_name ORDER BY 1) AS rn
  FROM   employee
)
SELECT first_name ||  
       last_name ||  
       CASE rn WHEN 1 THEN '' ELSE rn::varchar END || 
       '@mycompany.com' AS employee_email
FROM   e
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I'll study more about the query above =)